# Does the Psi Warrior Fighter's Telekinetic Movement feature allow you to move a grappled or restrained willing creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, forced-movement

> **Telekinetic Movement.** You can move an object or a creature with your mind. As an action, you target one loose object that is Large or smaller or one willing creature, other than yourself. If you can see the target and it is within 30 feet of you, you can move it up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space you can see. Alternatively, if it is a Tiny object, you can move it to or from your hand. Either way, you can move the target horizontally, vertically, or both. Once you take this action, you can't do so again until you finish a short or long rest, unless you expend a Psionic Energy die to take it again.

It lacks any clause for the creature, other than that they have to be willing, so can you move a willing restrained or grappled creature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes

There is no language restricting this, so you can absolutely move a restrained/grappled willing creature just like you could physically move them if you were within range.

Although there is language for the object around being 'loose' as a requirement, the creature option does not have that, so the above action is more than reasonable.